# Type annotation for modified function signature

Tags: python, python-decorators, type-hinting, mypy

I'd like to write a Python decorator which takes a function, and returns a modified function which takes the same arguments, but modifies the required types of the arguments, as well as the return type. I would like to be able to express these type changes in a manner that allows mistakes in calling code to be detected by MyPy or similar.

An example would be something like the following:

```py
from typing import Callable, Optional, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec('P')
R = TypeVar('R')

def preserve_nulls(f: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[???, Optional[R]]:
    
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        if any(value is None for value in args):
            return None
        elif any(value is None for value in kwargs.values()):
            return None
        else:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return inner
```

In this case, given a function `f` with signature `(foo: int, bar: str, baz: List[str]) -> int`, then the decorated function `preserve_nulls(f)` should have signature `(foo: Optional[int], bar: Optional[str], baz: Optional[List[str]]) -> Optional[int]`.

Expressing the new return type is simple, since I can just do `Optional[R]`. But I don't know what to replace the `???` in my above example with to essentially express "the result of applying `Optional` to every argument in `P`".

Ultimately, my goal is to find a suitable annotation for `preserve_nulls` such that given something like the following,

```
def f(foo: int, bar: str, baz: list[str]) -> int:
    return 0

wrapped_f = preserve_nulls(f)

correct = wrapped_f(foo=1, bar=None, baz=None)

incorrect = wrapped_f(foo='one', bar=None, baz=[None])
```

Then if I run it through MyPy (or another type checker), it will be happy that the `correct` call is valid, but complain that `foo` and `baz` have the wrong type in the `incorrect` call.

Ideally the solution should be adaptable to other 'modifications' other than just `Optional`, like say replacing each argument type `T` with `Callable[[], T]` or `List[T]` or whatever.

I am prepared for the possibility that this is simply not currently possible, but if it can be done then any help is much appreciated.